# Last week of year and 1st January with Carbon?

Tags: php, date, php-carbon, iso8601

I'm working on a project and I need to format date in the following : `YYYYWW`  where `WW` is the week number in the year, for example : today is `202131`.

There are several ways to do this, I can use `isoFormat('YYYYWW')` directly, or I can get `weekOfYear` attribute and append it to current year.

Both methods however, break for the following date : `01-01-2021`, indeed, the 1st january is set in the last week of 2020, but the year is 2021. Both methods give : `202153` while the correct result should be `202053` .

I currently have a workaround by checking if the month is less than 3 and the week is bigger than 50 then there is a problem and I decrement the year by 1.

```
public static function formatTestWeek($d)
{
    $current = Carbon::parse($d);
    $currentWeek = $current->weekOfYear;
    $currentYear = $current->year;
    if($currentWeek > 50 && $current->month < 3){
        $currentYear -= 1;
    }
    $formattedDate = strval($currentYear) . $current->isoFormat("WW");
    return $formattedDate;
}
```

Is there a more elegant approach in Carbon to get `YYYYWW` format that works in all cases ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`YYYY` is the year

`GGGG` is the ISO week-year

`gggg` is the week-year following current locale settings (`first_day_of_week` + `day_of_first_week_of_year`)

So you need `->isoFormat('GGGGWW')`

Complete list of codes available in `isoFormat()` are in the documentation:
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#iso-format-available-replacements

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful, I'm wondering though  why when I use $dt->weekYear I get 2021 and not 2020 ?

Comment: `$dt->weekYear` use locale config (`first_day_of_week` + `day_of_first_week_of_year`) so it's not the same depending if your locale is en_US, fr_FR, ar_AE, etc.
`$dr->locale('en_US')->weekYear` / `$dr->locale('fr_FR')->weekYear`
if you want ISO 8601 week, it's `$dt->isoWeekYear`